# Cast error from `try_into()` to custom error

Tags: error-handling, rust

This is a simplified version of some Rust code I have as part of a library:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::result;
use thiserror::Error;

pub type Result<T> = result::Result<T, MyError>;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    CrateXError(#[from] crate_x::Error),
}

pub fn my_function() -> Result<()> {
    // might return MyError::CrateXError
    crate_x::do_something()?;

    // in reality, get `x` from a database
    let x: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let x: [u8; 4] = x.try_into().unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", x);
    Ok(())
}
```

Here I'm using the imaginary crate `crate_x` for demonstration purposes, which implements its own `Error` type. I'm handling this in `MyError` using the `Error` macro from `thiserror`.

My goal is to replace `try_into().unwrap()` with `try_into()?` and handle the possible error as part of `MyError`.

I tried the following:

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    CrateXError(#[from] crate_x::Error),

    #[error(transparent)]
    TryIntoError(#[from] <[u8; 4] as TryFrom<Vec<u8>>>::Error),
}
```

However, I got the following error: ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36d44de10209cb4ab962eb82fb4e696d))

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<Error>` for type `Error`
```

My questions:

1. Is this an idiomatic way to handle errors from `try_into()` or should I do so differently, e.g. just unwrapping them? In my real application, the `Vec<u8>` *should* be the correct length, but may not be if the database where it comes from is corrupted by the end user.
2. If this is idiomatic, what is the correct syntax I should be using to make this work using the `Error` macro from `thiserror`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a “conflicting implementations” error, and there's not enough information to say (since you didn't provide concrete *compilable* code to investigate further).

That said, there's a deeper problem with this:

```rust
    #[error(transparent)]
    TryIntoError(#[from] <[u8; 4] as TryFrom<Vec<u8>>>::Error),
```

The result “error” type from `TryFrom<Vec<T>>` is just the vector itself. This is done so that if you wish to recover from the failure to convert, the vector hasn't been consumed and you can do further things with it. If you're merely letting the faulure propagate, you probably *don't* want to just hand that vector of four bytes to the caller. And, `#[error(transparent)]` can't work because a `Vec` doesn't implement `std::error::Error`.

So, for the case of the `try_into` failing, you probably *shouldn't* implement it as an automatic error conversion, but instead explicitly choose the interpretation using `map_err)`:

```rust
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    CrateXError(#[from] crate_x::Error),

    #[error("Corrupted database entry")]
    CorruptedData,
}

...

let x: [u8; 4] = x.try_into()
    .map_err(|_| MyError::CorruptedData)?;
```

This isn't just easier to make work: it also makes a *better abstraction* between the implementation details of your code and the interface it presents to callers. Your callers don't care that you're using `try_into`: they care about the information that *there was a problem with the data in the database*. In a fully fleshed out implementation, `CorruptedData` might have a field to store information identifying which record was corrupted, and perhaps which field, but the most generally useful information is that there *is* a bad record, thus indicating ways to recover (e.g. delete the record, skip it, reload from backup, or tell the user to try to fix it).

Similarly, having a `CrateXError` may or may not be a good idea, depending on whether it's a guaranteed API characteristic about *your* crate that it uses `crate_x`, and whether `crate_x` is even a relevant concept to what you're doing. Wrapping errors in a public error enum without thinking about what they mean will mean more breaking changes for your users when you change your implementation. (On the other hand, if you're writing a binary, or a library for your own use, then you don't need to worry about the type stability and should just design whatever's convenient for the error handling *you* are doing.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I've also added a link to a playground which demonstrates the error described in my question.

Comment: @DavidBailey I see. From the message I would guess that the specifically problem is that the `thiserror::Error` derive macro isn't correctly generating code given `<[u8; 4] as TryFrom<Vec<u8>>>::Error` as a type name. Conveniently, my answer's recommendation on design principles is to avoid doing that anyway.